# Using execCommand for formatting in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, wysiwyg

I have this code:

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  onClick(targetElement) {
    console.log(targetElement);
    var command = 'bold';
    if (command == 'h1' || command == 'h2' || command == 'p') {
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, command);
    } else document.execCommand(targetElement.data('command'), false, null);
  });
```

But this isn't working.  The first `if` statement will be skipped as I just want to ensure that the `execCommand` is working.

It does print out the `console.log` so it gets into that function.

The HTML element that will be modified is:

```
<div id='editor' contenteditable>
  <h1>A WYSIWYG Editor.</h1>
  <p>Change this text, or format</p>
</div>
```

How do I change the text that was selected, for bold?
How do I use document.execCommand in Typescript?

I have a feeling in this section, `document.execCommand(targetElement` that I should have passed in the div with id `editor` to the directive so it know what that particular button should act upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have `data` on your `document` object.

Anyways, you are passing in the `$event` into the `HostListener`. This will make the `targetElement` a `MouseEvent` instead of a `HTMLElement`. You can use type hinting to foresee such errors.

On the other hand you are using a `data` function, from which I've never heard of. Not on`MouseEvent` nor on a `HTMLElement` or `Document`. My guess is that you are trying to access the `dataset`? If that's the case, this might work for you:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(targetElement: Document) {
    let command: string = 'bold';
    if (command === 'h1' || command === 'h2' || command === 'p') {
       document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, command);
    } else {
       document.execCommand(targetElement.dataset['command'], false, null);
    }
}
```